# in Rails 3 what is "current_user"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

- is it something that the rails framework provides?
- can it be changed to "current_car"  - in this example, "car" being my object?

  so, can I use the "current_" and append the name of my object???

Comment: In order to do something like `current_car` you'd have to define what that actually means in your app; you could implement it similar to how the auth frameworks create a `current_user` function, but it certainly doesn't exist out-of-the-box.

Comment: so is this function from a gem? not from the framework?

Comment: I thought it was part of RAILS...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

current_user is a method defined by many authentication frameworks which are available for Rails. 
[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is one of the most popular authentication frameworks but there are many others you can find.

The method current_user usually returns the current authenticated user if there is one, or nil otherwise.

Of course you can't just replace the suffix of current_ with anything you'd like, it just won't work.

I don't see why you'd like to use current_car in your application but you can post it as a comment and I'll try to help you figure out if it is needed and what alternatives there are.

Comment: Oh so its something specific to a gem?

Comment: @BrianJosephSpinos No, it's part of many authorization frameworks, as the answer states: Rails has no concept of a "current user" other than the session, which is less a user than a browser.